# MVC - Entity Framework - Where does this belong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following simplified classes:

```
public class Customer
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   public List<Account> Accounts {get; set;}
}

public class Account
{ 
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public Customer Customer {get; set;}
   public int CustomerId {get; set;}
   public string AccountNumber {get; set;}
   public double AccountBalance {get; set;}
   public int? SupercededAccountId {get; set;}
}
```

So working with the Account class I need access to the superceded account which is just another account.  I have a record of the superceded account in the form of the id of the superceded account.  While I realize this is ugly and wrong I have added a method to the Account class to retrieve the account I need:

```
public Account SupercededAccount()
{
    if (SupercededAccountId != null)
    {
       using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
       {
          Account supercededAccount = db.Accounts.Find(SupercededAccountId);
          return supercededAccount;
        }
     }
     else return null;               
}
```

I need access to the superceded Account object not only in the account view, but reports and background tasks so I'd like it to be part of the Model class in some way.  What is the proper way to gain access to the superceded account values I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a navigator to the superseded Account

```
public class Account
{ 
   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}

   [ForgienKey("Customer")]
   public int CustomerId {get;set;}
   //navigator to customer
   public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;}
   public string AccountNumber {get; set;}
   public double AccountBalance {get; set;}

   [ForgienKey("SupercededAccount")]
   public int? SupercededAccountId {get; set;}

   public virtual Account SupercededAccount {get;set;}
}

public class Customer
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Ok perfect.  One step further.  I also need access to all prior accounts for this customer.  I left it off above but I also have a method to retrieve these which is basically the same as above except it returns a list of accounts where CustomerId = Account.CustomerId and != current Id

Comment: Updated, just use the accounts navigator and linq the one you want.

Comment: Can I put that in a method to have easy access?  So I could have a List<Account> PreviousAccounts() method in the Account class that returns Customer.Accounts.Where(i=>i.Id != this.Id)?

Comment: You could but I prefer to keep the entity classes lean and mean, the linq is so straightforward your not really saving much by having a direct access method. If you do make sure to check the collection for null before the query.